# Why can't I see images from my Fujifilm X E2 on Windows 10?

Tags: fujifilm, windows

After upgrading to Windows 10, I can no longer see photos from my X-E2 camera.

The camera is detected and Windows Explorer even tells me the amount of free space in the camera SD card. But when I double click on the folder it has no pictures, despite it knowing the card has 9GB of them! The images are in JPEG and RAW formats.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the drivers ?  What is the format of your file ?

Comment: Looks like you're not alone. Nikons are apparently affected as well. http://www.photographyblog.com/news/fuji_nikon_issue_windows_10_compatiblity_announcements/.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. It's not about the drivers, the camera is detected and windows explorer even tells me the amount of free space in the camera SD, but i double click on the folder and it has no pictures (while it knows the card has 9GB of them). The format is JPEG and RAW. I heard about nikon having the same issue. This is a no go for me in windows 10, but i was really liking it sooo, please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Fujifilm is in the process of addressing this issue:

http://www.fujifilm.com/news/n150811.html

They say they will have a firmware update for the X-E2 (amongst others) to resolve the issue "by the end of Aug 2015".

--

Edit: X-E2 firmware update to address this issue now available:

http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital_cameras/software/firmware/x/xe2/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I have the same isssue with my Fujifilm XE-2.  My Nikon D600 has no issues with windows 10.  the work around I use is to remove the card from the camera, insert it in the card reader and copy the files into a folder on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Fujifilm is only supplying USB/Firmware compatibility updates, for cameras, only older than 2010!!! That leaves people like me, with a Finepix S100fs out of luck! I am so upset!! However, the work around now, is to just use a card reader with SD card to get the pictures of the camera now.